# Popup panel not displaying errors / submitting

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, popup, richfaces

I am using JSF 2, with richfaces 4.x. I have created a login form which is in a popup. The popup does not submit and return the errors properly, nor does it allow me to login.

Here is my login popup:

[image: Before login attempt]

```
        <rich:popupPanel id="loginPopup">
            <h:form id="login" class="compact-form clearfix">
                <h1>Access your Account</h1>
                <fieldset id="inputs">
                    <h:outputLabel value="Username:" for="username"/><br/>
                    <h:inputText id="username" value="#{viewLogin.loginName}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter your username">
                        <f:validateLength maximum="20" minimum="3" />
                    </h:inputText>
                    <a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true">
                        <h:message for="username" />
                    </a4j:outputPanel>

                    <h:outputLabel value="Password:" for="password"/><br/>
                    <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{viewLogin.password}" required="true" requiredMessage="Enter your password">
                        <f:validator validatorId="LoginValidator" />
                        <f:validateLength maximum="20" minimum="5" />
                    </h:inputSecret>
                    <a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true">
                        <h:message for="password" />
                    </a4j:outputPanel>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="actions">
                    <a4j:commandButton value="Submit" id="submit" action="#{viewLogin.login()}" immediate="false" 
                           execute="username password @this"
                           render="username password"  oncomplete="if (#{facesContext.maximumSeverity == null}) {#{rich:component('loginPopup')}.hide();}"/>
                    <h:commandButton value="Cancel">
                        <rich:componentControl operation="hide" target="loginPopup"/>
                    </h:commandButton>
                    <h:link value="Forgot password?" outcome="forgotpassword"/>
                    <h:link value="Forgot username?" outcome="forgotusername"/>
                    <h:link value="Create account" outcome="createuser"/>
                </fieldset>
            </h:form> 
        </rich:popupPanel>
```

Now when i press the submit button the h:inputSecret styles get changed around and the field is no login a input type password and will show my password.

[image: after submit]

Why is my login not submitting for validation / rendering errors?

Note: The form works without the popup and a4j tags.

Comment: Also, for testing purpose, add a general rich:messages/h:messages to check if something else is there it complains about - don't forget to let that have rerendered..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just double-checked your source code in RF 4.3.3.Final, just removing the `LoginValidator` you are using, but was not provided :

```
<rich:popupPanel id="loginPopup" show="true">
    <h:form id="login" class="compact-form clearfix">
        <h1>Access your Account</h1>
        <fieldset id="inputs">
            <h:outputLabel value="Username:" for="username"/><br/>
            <h:inputText id="username" value="#{viewLogin.loginName}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter your username">
                <f:validateLength maximum="20" minimum="3" />
            </h:inputText>
            <a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true">
                <h:message for="username" />
            </a4j:outputPanel>
             <h:outputLabel value="Password:" for="password"/><br/>
             <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{viewLogin.password}" required="true" requiredMessage="Enter your password">
                <f:validateLength maximum="20" minimum="5" />
             </h:inputSecret>
             <a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true">
                <h:message for="password" />
             </a4j:outputPanel>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="actions">
            <a4j:commandButton value="Submit" id="submit" action="#{viewLogin.login()}" immediate="false"
                   execute="username password @this"
                   render="username password"  oncomplete="if (#{facesContext.maximumSeverity == null}) {#{rich:component('loginPopup')}.hide();}"/>
            <h:commandButton value="Cancel">
                <rich:componentControl operation="hide" target="loginPopup"/>
            </h:commandButton>
        </fieldset>
    </h:form>
</rich:popupPanel>
```

with a minimized Seam 2.1.3.CR1 injected Bean

```
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Name;

@Name("viewLogin")
public class TestBean {

private String loginName;
private String password;

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getLoginName() {
    return loginName;
}
public void setLoginName(String loginName) {
    this.loginName = loginName;
}

public String login() {
    System.out.println("Login called");
    return "";
}
}
```

and the `inputSecret` field stays secret. My suggestion would be

- to add a global `h:messages` (has to be rerendered with the button click) or a global `rich:messages` to check for other possible reasons.
- also double-check the LoginValidator-Bean for any possible problems
- be sure there is no other PhaseListener/JavaScript actively changing the DOM

Sometimes, popupPanel shows strange behaviour in combination with forms (being nested forms. You can modify the DOM Element attaching via the attribute `domElementAttachment`.

Hope it helps...